# How to stop automatic time update via terminal?

Tags: command-line, time, date

This question shows how to stop automatic time update (and switch to manual):

[How to stop automatic time update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176174/how-to-stop-automatic-time-update/176184#176184?newreg=c1754c5e75974b12a49e2ea5fba0070b)

I want to do this exact thing but I can only ssh onto my machine so I need to make this change through the terminal. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I disable ntpd?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29663/how-do-i-disable-ntpd)

Comment: @AizuddinZali I would say it isn't - since he gets errors telling him that ntp.service isn't loaded and `sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop` doesn't work - see comments on my answer

Comment: yes, it has to do with gnome time & date setting.

Comment: Right, I'm just wondering id there's a way to change settings from terminal, or is there a file somewhere I need to change a line of? I tried 'conf watch /' while I changed the setting in the gui but it didn't show anything (but changing some other settings did)

Comment: ntp and GNOME Automatic Date & Time **isn't** the same.

Comment: And it's not a dconf thing o_O – very interesting

Comment: You could block the port on the outbound firewall.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

GNOME Automatic Date & Time doesn't use the ntp service, installable via `sudo apt-get install ntp`. Therefore stopping or uninstalling the service doesn't help.

Systemd `timedatectl` is used, therefore one  command to switch off

```
timedatectl set-ntp 0
```

and one command to switch on

```
timedatectl set-ntp 1
```

---

*Example*

[image]

```
% timedatectl set-ntp 1
```

[image]

or via `timedatectl status`

```
% timedatectl status
      Local time: Do 2015-10-08 18:17:17 CEST
  Universal time: Do 2015-10-08 16:17:17 UTC
        RTC time: Do 2015-10-08 16:17:17
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
                  So 2015-03-29 01:59:59 CET
                  So 2015-03-29 03:00:00 CEST
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
                  So 2015-10-25 02:59:59 CEST
                  So 2015-10-25 02:00:00 CET

% timedatectl set-ntp 1

% timedatectl status
      Local time: Do 2015-10-08 18:17:35 CEST
  Universal time: Do 2015-10-08 16:17:35 UTC
        RTC time: Do 2015-10-08 16:17:35
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
                  So 2015-03-29 01:59:59 CET
                  So 2015-03-29 03:00:00 CEST
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
                  So 2015-10-25 02:59:59 CEST
                  So 2015-10-25 02:00:00 CET
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. This is the setting that is changed when you switch between manual and automatic in the System Settings

Comment: the logs show it only synced when I restarted the service. do I need to create a cron to sync it every day?

Answer (score 8):

On a systemd operating system like Ubuntu 15.04 use the `timedatectl` utility, which makes the same Desktop Bus RPC calls as the GNOME control centre utility does:

```
timedatectl set-ntp false
```

### Further reading

- [`timedatectl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/timedatectl.1.html). Ubuintu 15.04 manual pages.  Canonical.
- [`timedatectl`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is not `ntpd` which is not installed by default. It's an `if-up.d` script which run time update whenever a network interface activated.

- `dconf watch /` shows nothing but **`inotifywait -m -r /etc/`** will do. Here is the interesting output:

  ```
  /etc/network/if-up.d/ MOVED_FROM ntpdate
  /etc/network/if-up.d/ MOVED_TO ntpdate.disabled
  ```
- It belongs to **ntpdate** package.

  ```
  $ dpkg -S /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
  ntpdate: /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
  ```
- So to disable time update, rename that file same as the control center does:

  ```
  sudo mv /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate.disabled
  ```

Comment: I was also irritated, `dconf watch /` shows a change for the timezone, but not for the automatic date/time settings. Good one =)