# How to edit /etc/default/ntpdate and prevent ntpdate from ever running without uninstalling

Tags: security, ntp

Since [both ntpd and ntpdate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641158/how-does-ubuntu-synchronize-time-without-ntp/643075) rely on ntp servers, and since the Ubuntu repos have yet to complete an update of ntp to 4.2.8p4 (the version [recommended by ntp researchers](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/10/new-attacks-on-network-time-protocol-can-defeat-https-and-create-chaos/)), I expect this means that both ntpdate and ntpd are vulnerable on my laptop (or at the very least, capable of connecting my laptop to any number of vulnerable ntp servers through either mechanism, so it's not sufficient to just stop ntpd alone).

I don’t feel confident about reviewing code and updating to the new version of ntp 4.2.8p4 myself. At the same time, I would like the packages to remain installed so that when future updates become available in the repos, I will be notified by Software Updater.

So my question is **not** "How to update?" **nor** “How to uninstall?”, but rather how do I simply disable or ‘turn off’ both ntpd and ntpdate, so they do not ever run or log any activity, without uninstalling them?”

[How do I disable ntpd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29663/how-do-i-disable-ntpd) suggest I can simply prevent ntpd running at all using

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ntp remove
```

and prevent ntpdate running at all by adding `exit 0` to `/etc/default/ntpdate`.

However, I do not know how/where in the file to place the line `exit 0`.

Do I just use an editor like vi or nano to write in `exit 0` on any line without a `#` comment symbol, and it will be interpreted by the system correctly?  Can someone please confirm / elaborate on this solution?

Comment: You should be able to add the `exit 0` to the bottom of the `ntpdate` file so that the `ntpd` sees that it exited with `0` which means something to `ntpd`.  Certain scripts and files have different exit codes meaning different things.

Answer (score 1):

A miniscule amount of research (`locate ntp | grep /etc`) led me to `/etc/init.d/ntp` which starts `ntp`, and is linked to by the startup scripts in the `/etc/rc?.d` directories (on my Ubuntu Linux 14.04.3 LTS system, YMMV):

```
/etc/rc1.d/K77ntp -> ../init.d/ntp
/etc/rc2.d/S23ntp -> ../init.d/ntp
/etc/rc3.d/S23ntp -> ../init.d/ntp
/etc/rc4.d/S23ntp -> ../init.d/ntp
/etc/rc5.d/S23ntp -> ../init.d/ntp
```

`/etc/init.d/ntp` contains the lines:

```
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/ntpd
PIDFILE=/var/run/ntpd.pid

test -x $DAEMON || exit 5
```

So, a simple `sudo chmod -x /usr/sbin/ntpd` will keep `ntpd` from ever running, until the file is replaced by an updated version of `ntpd`.

Working off the same miniscule amount of research also led me to `/etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate`, which contains:

```
# Check whether ntpdate was removed but not purged; it's useless to wait for 
# it in that case.
if [ ! -x /usr/sbin/ntpdate-debian ] && [ -d /usr/sbin ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

So, `sudo chmod -x /usr/sbin/ntpdate-debian` will keep `ntpdate-debian` from ever running, until the file is replaced by an updated version of `ntpdate-debian`.

There are other `ntp*` files in `/usr/sbin`, but they are all in either the `ntp` or `ntpdate` packages:

```
$ echo /usr/sbin/ntp*| xargs -n 1 dpkg -S
ntp: /usr/sbin/ntpd
ntpdate: /usr/sbin/ntpdate
ntpdate: /usr/sbin/ntpdate-debian
ntp: /usr/sbin/ntp-keygen
ntp: /usr/sbin/ntptime
ntp: /usr/sbin/ntp-wait
```

so they will all be replaced when you update the `ntp` and `ntpdate` packages. Therefore, you could:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/sbin/ntp*
```

But, the Threat and Risk Analysis part of my mind asks, is this really worth the effort? What is the Threat? Your system could be lied to about the time. What is the Risk? If your laptop thinks it is the incorrect time, what will go wrong? Will the World end? Will you leave work hours later than you want?

I think there are bigger Threats and Risks in areas other than the time-of-day.

As always, YMMV.

Comment: A miniscule amount of research (my second link) might lead one to at least skim the relevant link above discussing why NTP researchers recommended the update; this bit, for instance, seems to address the question that the Threat and Risk Analysis part of your mind asks: "the attacks can be used to snoop on encrypted traffic or to bypass important security measures such as DNSSEC specification preventing the tampering of domain name system records. The most troubling scenario involves bypassing HTTPS encryption by forcing a computer to accept an expired transport layer security certificate."

Comment: Especially the paragraph starting "It's not clear how practical some of the attacks would be in real-world settings. A desktop computer with a clock that was set to a date months or years in the past would almost certainly be easy to detect. And it wouldn't be surprising if the incorrect time would trigger errors from the operating system or other applications.". If it's really a problem for you, you could `apt-get purge ntp ntpdate`, then download, build, install and configure the version you like. It is FOSS.

Answer (score 0):

As with many other software available packaged in the Ubuntu repositories:

## Don't go by upstream version numbers alone.

Ubuntu backports security fixes, especially for software in the `main` repository, including `ntp` and `ntpdate`.

In this case, the fixes were backported back in October. See [USN-2783-1](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2783-1/):

> Aanchal Malhotra, Isaac E. Cohen, and Sharon Goldberg discovered that
>   NTP incorrectly handled restarting after hitting a panic threshold. A
>   remote attacker could possibly use this issue to alter the system time
>   on clients. (CVE-2015-5300)
>
> ---
>
> Aanchal Malhotra, Isaac E. Cohen, and Sharon Goldberg discovered that
>   NTP incorrectly handled rate limiting. A remote attacker could
>   possibly use this issue to cause clients to stop updating their clock.
>   (CVE-2015-7704, CVE-2015-7705)
>
> ---
>
> #### Update instructions
>
> The problem can be corrected by updating your system to the following
>   package version:
>
> - Ubuntu 15.10: ntp `1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu8.1`
> - Ubuntu 15.04: ntp `1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu6.2`
> - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: ntp `1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.04.5`
> - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: ntp `1:4.2.6.p3+dfsg-1ubuntu3.6`

Note these are the CVEs listed in [the source](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~goldbe/NTPattack.html) for the Ars Technica article you linked to.

When in doubt, look at the [Ubuntu Security Notices](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/) and [the Ubuntu CVE tracker](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/).